# Is it possible to permalink to a location within an MP3 file?

Tags: mp3, bookmarks

YouTube has a cool feature where you can link to locations within a video. e.g.:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WvDedo8r1Fk#t=41s

Is there a way to do this with audio (e.g. MP3) files, preferably those hosted on the web?

Like:

http://example.com/episodes/1.mp3#t=41s

I'd like to build a library of interesting moments within podcast episodes, so I can easily reference and jump back to that location later. e.g. I want to be able to record that someone said an interesting story in "This American Life", Episode 5, at 45 minutes and 10 seconds. It would be nice if I could do this without requiring a complex software setup on my PC or iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is, actually. With HTML5 audio, you can [specify the playback range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Specifying_playback_range) in the hash.

```
http://foo.com/video.ogg#t=10,20
Specifies that the video should play the range 10 seconds through 20 seconds.
http://foo.com/video.ogg#t=,10.5
Specifies that the video should play from the beginning through 10.5 seconds.
http://foo.com/video.ogg#t=,02:00:00
Specifies that the video should play from the beginning through two hours.
http://foo.com/video.ogg#t=60,
Specifies that the video should start playing at 60 seconds and play through the end of the video.
```

Tried this on some random MP3 file I googled up and it works fine for me in Google Chrome on OS X:

http://www.dandeacon.com/mp3/06%20Porky%20Pig%20EP/03%20rocket%20problems.mp3#t=10,12

The one thing that doesn't seem to work is `#t=10,` to play from 10 secs until the end. But `#t=10,999` worked fine.

I wouldn't expect this to work across all browsers, though. New versions of Chrome, Safari and Firefox are likely supported, but IE tends to disappoint.

Comment: Great, thanks! Too bad that unlike YouTube it downloads the entire file even when I only need a small segment, but at least this gives me what I was looking for.